# SCOTUS reject request to prevent PA from doing it

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

The structure "SCOTUS rejects Mr.R's request **to** prevent PA from doing it" appears to have two opposite meanings to me:

1. It means "SCOTUS rejects Mr.R's request so that 'PA doing it' can be prevented."
2. It means "SCOTUS rejects Mr.R's request, this request is that 'PA doing it' should be prevented" (Now SCOTUS has rejected the request, so 'PA doing it in favor of Biden is successful').

I guess (2) is what the author means. But I am not absolutely sure.

> SCOTUSblog
> @SCOTUSblog
>
> The Supreme Court has rejected a Pennsylvania Republican congressman’s **request to prevent Pennsylvania** from certifying its presidential election results in favor of Joe Biden.
>
> This case is different from the lawsuit filed by the state of Texas this morning.

[Source of article](https://twitter.com/SCOTUSblog/status/1336428598568349702)

Comment: The congressman’s request was "to prevent Pennsylvania from certifying its presidential election results." The Supreme Court has rejected this request. In other words, PA can certify the election result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plain meaning here is clearly (2). If the author wanted to ensure it was read as (1), they would probably add commas and perhaps "in order":

> ...has rejected a congressman's request, in order to prevent Pennsylvania...